# In python how would I paste chunks of code

Tags: python, tkinter, clipboard, pyautogui

I'm trying to write a python script which would allow me to paste large pieces of code. Now I can get the system to paste text from a variable. However the code I want to paste is long and has a lot of special characters in it. Is there any way I can get around this easily?

Here is the code I have at present.

```
import pyautogui
from tkinter import Tk
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
result = 'Text to Paste'

x, y = pyautogui.position()
pyautogui.click(x, y)
pyautogui.typewrite(result)
```

Comment: What problem exactly are you trying to solve? Neither "long" nor "special characters" are really a problem for a system paste operation. And what is the problem with the code you have now?

Comment: I don't understand how to save them to a variable. Here is an image of me trying to put some code in: https://imgur.com/XdkC5C1

Comment: Quote the piece of code using `'''`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyautogui, time, pyperclip # pyperclip used for copy and paste

var1 = ("words block here") # you replace this with large words

pyautogui.click(x=399, y=600) # click where you want to paste "var1" value

time.sleep(1) # delay

pyperclip.copy(var1)  # variable that stores your pasting block

time.sleep(1) # delay

pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "v") # and paste it with pyautogui.
```